# What are the usage limits for metamask?

Tags: metamask

Metamask loads data from the blockchain into my browser, it's a light client.

How much data can I load until it stops. There must be some type of resource limit involved here...

I'm sure metamask doesn't want us using the client as a CDN to deliver large resources.

Answer (score 5):

Metamask uses Infura for its backend to interact with the blockchain. Currently Infura does not enforce any limits right now. But please do give us a heads up if you're launching a huge dApp or doing a token launch, so we can help you guys out with it.

Answer (score 0):

Metamask stores your account keys locally. It does not load the blockchain data. So you don't need to worry about the amount of that is loaded.

It uses web3.js to fetch your account balances. It signs the transaction using your keys and broadcasts to ethereum network.

Comment: This isn't accurate, MetaMask uses a backend service (Infura) to provide read data from the blockchain. I've reached out to Infura to comment on exact limits.

Comment: @DanF did you get an answer?

Comment: erkt above is from Infura.